# Anyone know a slick way to find all references to an MVC EditorTemplate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-editor-templates, editortemplates

One of my favorite features in Asp.NET MVC (v2 and higher) is Editor / Display templates.  They are a great tool for encapsulating rendering logic for a given object type.  However, when templates (particularly EditorTemplates) start to contain more complicated logic and get applied in a variety of circumstances, they can become somewhat brittle and pose a testing challenge given that there is no way to "find all references."

Some of this can obviously be avoided by opting to override templates more frequently rather than trying to handle too many cases in a shared template.  But forgetting design considerations - anyone have a suggestion for a good way to locate all the "EditorFor" / "DisplayFor" references that invoke a given template?  I'm open to using third party IDE plugins like ReSharper.